# Metric space with two similar points which are not in the same orbit.

Tags: metric-spaces, examples-counterexamples, isometry

Is there an example of a metric space $X$ with two points $p$ and $q$ so that for every $r>0$ the ball with radius $r$ and center $p$ is isometric to the ball with radius $r$ and center $q$ and yet no automorphism of $X$ sends $p$ to $q$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, such spaces exist. See this MathOverflow answer for two nice examples: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/182719/if-all-balls-at-x-and-y-are-isometric-is-there-an-isometry-sending-x-to-y

Comment: Though the link may provide an answer, it is better to include the essentials of the answer in your post.